# Insomnia Rest Client - Get header from response with multiple values

Tags: insomnia

I'm trying to parse the Set-Cookie header from a response.

I do,

`Response - reference values from other request's response.`

`Header - value of of response header.`

`Request - ..`

`Header name - Set-Cookie`

and the choices I get are:

```
Choices are [
    "Date",
    "Server",
    "WWW-Authenticate",
    "Content-Length",
    "Set-Cookie",
    "Set-Cookie",
    "Set-Cookie",
    "Content-Language",
    "X-Powered-By",
    "Cache-Control",
    "Pragma",
    "Content-Type"
]
```

When I enter in Header Name: Set-Cookie, it seems that I only get the first one. How can I get the second or third?